# Java Generic Question: Any better way?

Tags: java, generics

[Update]: my initial example doesn't reflect my problem. Updated the sample, hopfully it is better now.

Java Generic and overloading don't play well together.

```
public interface Request<E> {
  E getValue();
}
```

I have a generic parameterized Request interface as above, and I would like write a DataStore class to save the payload request carries. The save logic is different for different payload type.

What I really want is something like

```
public interface DataStore {
  void save(Request<E1> r);
  void save(Request<E2> r);
}
```

But this is of course illegal.

If I want to preserve type safety, DataStore must declare different methods for each type I want to handle, e.g

```
public interface DataStore {
  // here E1 is the actual type I want to handle, not a generic parameter
  public void saveE1(Request<E1> e); 

  public void saveE2(Request<E2> e);
}
```

Or sacrifices type safety

```
public class DataStore {
  public void save(Request e) {
    Object value = e.getValue();
    if (value instanceof ReqE1Impl) {
      // do something
    } else if (value instanceof ReqE2Impl) {
      // do something else
    }
  }
}
```

Both ways suck! Is there any better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better way to do this would involve the object knowing how to save itself.  If you still want to use a DataStore, you could do something like this:

```
interface YourInterface {
  void save();
}

interface Request<E extends YourInterface> { 
  E getValue(); 
} 

class DataStore<E extends YourInterface> {
  public void save(Request<E> r) {
    r.getValue().save();
  }
}
```

You just have to ensure that your objects then each implement that `interface` and viola, you have Generics and polymorphism playing nice with each other.

NOTE:  The way your (revised) question is written, you are not using polymorphism.  You are using overloading.  Method overloading is decided at compile time, while method polymorphism is decided at runtime.  This is part of why you are running into these difficulties.

If you really do not want the above kind of design where the objects do all the work of saving themselves, then perhaps you can do something like this (as a very weak example):

```
interface YourInterface {
  String serialize();
}

interface Request<E extends YourInterface> { 
  E getValue(); 
} 

class DataStore<E extends YourInterface> {
  public void save(Request<E> r) {
    String value = r.getValue().serialize();
    // Now do something with value to save to a datastore
  }
}
```

Above is a weak example, but the main idea is that the objects know how to do the part of serialization that differs between objects, and the DataStore can then do the work that is common to all of your objects.

And yes, you are right (with the wrong terminology) -- generics don't play nice with overloading.  But they do play nice with polymorphism.  Polymorphism is usually a better instrument than overloading anyway.

Comment: Upvoted. You are right at pointing out my revised example is really about overloading.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding the question, but generics seem to solve this ok:

```
public interface Handler<E> {
    void save (E obj, DataStore<E> store);
}

public interface DataStore<E> {
    public void save (E obj);
}

public class AHandler implements Handler<String> {
    public void save (String obj, DataStore<String> obj2) {

    }
}

public class BHandler implements Handler<Boolean> {
    public void save (Boolean b1, DataStore<Boolean> obj3) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's another way to achieve what you're trying to do with that design.

Without knowing the specifics of the `E` type, I can only make the following general suggestions:

- Possibly `DataStore` should only deal with specific subtypes of `E`? You could parameterize the `DataStore` interface to ensure type safety that way, i.e. each `Handler<E>` accepts a `DataStore<E>`.
- Alternatively, consider moving the save functionality into the implementation of your `E` type - that way, `DataStore` doesn't need to be concerned with the exact type of `E`.

Comment: But E, a data object, should not know how to save itself. It is the responsibility of the DataStore.

Comment: indeed - in that case, perhaps the DataStore interface is too general? How about defining just one save(E) method - and implementations of that interface would handle specific types of E?

Comment: Where does that "should" come from? More to the point, why should anything other than an instance of E know how to save an instance of E?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem is with the generics, but rather with the design.

What you are saying is that you are passing an instance of a subclass of E, and essentially need to run a special handler corresponding to that specific class. So you essentially have two parallel hierarchies. This is a fairly common design problem.

If you are creating Es with a factory method, then you should have a factory method that obtains the appropriate SaveToDatastoreHandler based on the E. You pass that saver to the function, and it invokes polymorphically.

You may still have a switch, but at least now you isolate it to a factory method.